# Weird CodeIgniter Upload Problem

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

Here's the lowdown. PHP, Codeigniter, LAMP.

I've created a fixeee for you all to see my code. http://fixee.org/paste/s8jc04t/

Whenever I have mulitple file uploads (ex. fileupload1, fileupload2, fileupload3, etc.) and I tried to get the upload data from each one correctly, I seem to duplicate the first file data that was uploaded. Can someone help, the fixee explains everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put this line before each upload statement.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

that code will reset all config options to the default and then use your configs for the next file without reloading the library over and over.

Comment: You misspelled it, but you're right. It's $this->upload->initialize($config);

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should re-initialize the library. load the config again and initialize the library:

```
$config['var'] = 'value';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: The idea is to clear the variables in the upload class. Try clearing them by initialization and you'll be ok.